# Are these answers not answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

If I'm understanding correctly any "Answer" that doesn't answer the question directly or is a response to another answer should be "Not an Answer".

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background) and noticed it had two answers that I would consider better off as edits but have received upvotes.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11121897/3724365)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29164604/3724365)

Am I understanding the Not an Answer flag properly or are these answers different enough to warrant their own answer rather than an edit on the original answer.

Comment: Mods can't see the question in the context of the answer; if the answer looks like an answer, NAA can't be used on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since when were answers not allowed to reference or build on top of existing answers?

While I can't necessarily argue context, it does seem to me that the late answer is still a valid answer to the question.  It simply gives more affirmation that, even after three years, this approach works with Android Lollipop, and provides another technique to accomplish the original question's mission.

Personally I think it's fine.  Editing them together doesn't make any sense since it's two different users posting two different [enough] things.